# Angular 9 Variable not updating in View

Tags: angular, typescript, view, casting, angular9

I have a variable in my Component that it is updating while using `console.log(variable)` although it is not updating in my View using `{{ variable }}` I have tried several things, my last option was to use `Observers` and still not working as it should.

I'll explain my code:

So I have a Service, a Base Component, an App Component & another Component

My Base Component doesn't have any view. It only instantiates services. just like so:

```
  private _communicationService: CommunicationService;
  private _clientService: ClientService;

  constructor(private injector : Injector) {
    this.clientService = this.injector.get(ClientService);
  }
```

(Includes gets and setters)

My App Component and the other one, extends BaseComponent

**What I think it's wrong in my implementation is the next thing:**

My App Component is calling `window` functions that I tried to implement on my ngInit

```
export class AppComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit{  
  constructor(injector : Injector) {
    super(injector);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    window.FlashExternalInterface.logLoginStep = (step : string) => {
      this.clientService.loadClientProgress(step);
    }
  }
}
```

**My "other" component:**

```
export class LoaderComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit {
  public progress = 0;

  constructor(injector : Injector) {
    super(injector);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.clientService.clientProgress.subscribe(data => {
      console.log("Data Changing?: " + data);
      this.progress = data;
      console.log("Progress changing??" + this.progress);
    });
  }
}
```

My `progress` variable does change in F12 Console, but doesn't in the View.

I have tried using `{{ this.progress }}` AND without `this.` or even calling direct service instance from Base Component `clientService.clientProgress.getValue()`

I mean, the window function it's giving me an error in console like:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'logLoginStep' of undefined.
```

But still, the variable does change in console.
[Console Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beyyC.png)

Comment: Please reproduce this issue in stackblitz

Comment: I dont use this project as a Website, just as a extensión, I can't reproduce the actual issue without calling the ```window.FlashExternalInterface.LogLoginStep``` function, I have tried using a button that Will call my service function AND It does work properly, but when triggering by the window function doesn't do it

Comment: Based on that previous comment of mine, I would think that the function doesn't work, but It does, my console.log functions are being called just not updated in view

Comment: can you share your view code?

Comment: I solved this long time ago, tho I was reading my previous questions and I forgot to comment my solution. Since I was using external JS Functions such as 'logLoginStep' from another script outside my application I had to use something called NgZone which allowed me to run and rewrite code outside my app.  And then subscriptions did work well as it should

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an asynchronous issue, as `progress` is assigned a value within a `subscribe()` call. Prior to the data coming back from the client service, `progress` will not have been updated.

The reason your `console.log` is working is because it is within your `subscribe()` block therefore it is by definition waiting for the service to return the value before logging to the console. Your HTML however is instructed to render the current value of `progress` as soon as the page has loaded. Even though your `subscribe()` is called within `ngOnInit()`, it still takes a non-zero amount of time for the service to return the updated value, which is already too late.

There are a couple of ways to handle this in your HTML

**async pipe**

`<p>{{ progress | async }}<p>`

This will watch the `progress` variable for updates and render the changes to the DOM directly once the value has updated; effectively the same as what `.subscribe()` does in your .ts file

***ngIf**

`<p *ngIf="progress">{{ progress }}</p>`

This will not render the `<p>` at all until the `progress` variable is truthy, i.e. in this case not `0`, `null` or `undefined`